# sql:using not in and select nothing

Tags: mysql, sql

table 'tree':

```
+----+------+
| id | p_id |
+----+------+
| 1  | null |
| 2  | 1    |
| 3  | 1    |
| 4  | 2    |
| 5  | 2    |
+----+------+
```

and these codes select nothing out.why?

```
select id,'Leaf' as type
from tree
where  id not in (select distinct p_id from tree)
```

while these is working right,using two times for a same condition

```
SELECT
    id, 'Leaf' AS Type
FROM
    tree
WHERE
    id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT
            p_id
        FROM
            tree
        WHERE
            p_id IS NOT NULL)
        AND p_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: `NOT IN (..., null-value,  ...)` is never TRUE. Use `NOT EXISTS` instead.

Comment: @jarlh ok..I see ..thanks for  your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `NOT IN` with a subquery.  As Jarlh says in a comment, when *any* value is `NULL`, then no rows are returned at all.

Instead, get used to `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.id, 'Leaf' as type
from tree t
where not exists (select 1 from tree t2 where t2.p_id = t.id);
```

This behaves as you would expect.

Although you *could* fix the problem using `WHERE t2.p_id IS NOT NULL` in the subquery, you might as well use `NOT EXISTS`.  At some future point, you'll find yourself debugging another `NOT IN` where you left out the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: why we cant use null in subquery why it gives empty result set #Gordon

Comment: @Man You should read about three-valued logic in SQL. That might clear that out.